# "ganz gut auch" in this Kafka passage

Tags: meaning-in-context

The question is on *ganz gut auch* in this passage from Kafka's Der Verschollene.

Therese is describing the night before her mother's death, when the penniless mother and daughter were ineffectually searching for shelter.

> In manchen Zimmern, an denen sie vorüberkamen, waren die Türen geöffnet, um eine erstickende Luft herauszulassen, und aus dem rauchigen Dunst, der, wie durch einen Brand verursacht, die Zimmer erfüllte, trat nur die Gestalt irgend jemandes hervor, der im Türrahmen stand und entweder durch seine stumme Gegenwart oder durch ein kurzes Wort die Unmöglichkeit eines Unterkommens in dem betreffenden Zimmer bewies. Therese schien es jetzt im Rückblick, daß die Mutter nur in den ersten Stunden ernstlich einen Platz suchte, denn nachdem etwa Mitternacht vorüber war, hat sie wohl niemanden mehr angesprochen, obwohl sie mit kleinen Pausen bis zur Morgendämmerung nicht aufhörte weiterzueilen und obwohl in diesen Häusern, in denen weder Haustore noch Wohnungstüren je verschlossen werden, immerfort Leben ist und einem auf Schritt und Tritt Menschen begegnen. Natürlich war es kein Laufen, das sie rasch weiterbrachte, sondern es war nur die äußerste Anstrengung, deren sie fähig waren, und es konnte in Wirklichkeit **ganz gut auch** bloß ein Schleichen sein.

**QUESTION**

What exactly is the contribution of the phrase to the meaning of the clause, which, without it, (I think) would have meant, "and it could be in reality only a creeping"?

**BACKGROUND**

My (somewhat wild) guess is

- *ganz gut* and *auch* are two separate elements.
- *ganz gut* goes with *konnte* to form something like English *might well*.
- *auch* is emphasizing *bloß* or maybe the whole clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Draw a line between `ganz gut` and `auch bloß`. Alternatively to

> ... und es konnte in Wirklichkeit **ganz gut auch bloß** ein
>   Schleichen sein.

you could say

> ... und es konnte in Wirklichkeit **ohne weiteres auch nur** ein
>   Schleichen sein.

You can understand `ganz gut` as an expression of possibility/likelihood and `auch bloß` as a synonym of `lediglich` (merely) resp. `auch lediglich`.

As a substitute for `ganz gut` may also be used `gut und gern` in this case.

Comment: Your line-drawing between the two elements is what I should have expected; but see the other answer (by Serafina), treating of the phase as a single unit (or at least seeing *auch* as not particularly attached to *bloß*), and four upvotes to it.  Can there be such a difference of opinion on this?

Comment: @Catomic: Both is possible, you also could draw the line between `ganz gut auch` and `bloß`. Then you would take `ganz gut auch` as `auch ganz gut` with unusual [style driven] word positioning.

Answer (score 3):

I'd parse this as 'ganz gut auch' modifying 'konnte', meaning something along the lines of 'it might as well have been'. The 'auch' I'd consider more of a filler word.

Comment: this is exactly the way it is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

Translating the whole sentence to keep the context, I would choose:

"Natürlich war es kein Laufen, das sie rasch weiterbrachte, sondern es war nur die äußerste Anstrengung, deren sie fähig waren, und es konnte in Wirklichkeit **ganz gut auch bloß ein** Schleichen sein."

"Of course it wasn't running that moved them onward, rather it was just the most extreme effort that they were capable of, and in reality if could have **actually just been a** sneaking."

Without focusing on whether "sneaking" is there the correct translation for "schleichen", my point is that in common English use this situation could well use the "filler" of "actually".